# What is ()=>Method Syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I encountered this for the first time a few days ago when doing research about starting threads with parameters.

The answer which worked ivolved writing something like this:

```
Thread[i] thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>myMethod(myArg)));
```

This worked brilliantly, however, I have no idea what it is called, what the `()=>Method` syntax does or how/why it works.

If anyone could explain this to me I would be grateful!

Comment: You are looking for [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: very happy angel emoji